# Why are links rendering the full Sitecore content path?

Tags: sxa, link-manager

I'm upgrading from SXA 1.9 to 10.2 and have noticed that links on the front-end are rendering the full Sitecore content path such as `/sitecore/content/tenant/site/home/path`. What can I check to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a change in a recent release of Sitecore / SXA. The fix is simple - you need to **set a default language on the site definition** for the site. I'm not sure if it is a SXA specific issue or a XM platform issue.

For non-SXA sites - this would be in the `<site>` config file.

For SXA sites - this would be on the Site Grouping item:

[image: SXA site grouping language]